# Validation exception

Tags: excel, vba

was wondering if anyone could help with creating and exception for a specific field on my user form, specifically my search field for populating the other fields in the form.  This will not be populated when submitting data to the worksheet.  Thank you in advance!!!!

```
Dim Ctrl As Control
For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
        If Ctrl.Value = vbNullString Then
            MsgBox "You must complete all entries"
            Ctrl.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
Next Ctrl
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to exclude one textbox from the piece of code given above.

Let's assume the textbox you want to exclude has the name `txtSearch` then you could use the following code

```
Dim Ctrl As Control
    For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            If Ctrl.Name <> "txtSearch" Then
                If Ctrl.Value = vbNullString Then
                    MsgBox "You must complete all entries"
                    Ctrl.SetFocus
                    Exit Sub
                End If

            End If
        End If
    Next Ctrl
```